# Using abstract classes and Interfaces

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

If I have three classes

```
class A

class B extends A

class C extends A
```

Would using abstract classes or interfaces give me any type of errors or affect the way I implement the program?

Comment: It depends.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: The way you're asking this is so vague that I would almost consider it not to be a real question. Read up on subclassing, interfaces, and abstract classes, and try to ask something more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you need to share implementation, favor interfaces.

If you need to share implementation, think carefully if an abstract class is the right way to accomplish this.

Inheritance is a powerful tool, but can easily create an unmaintainable mess (I have been guilty here).

But to answer your question - no, there is nothing inherent in this setup that would cause an "error".

Answer (score 1):

You should generally prefer interfaces whenever you can. Java's lack of multiple inheritance quickly becomes a limiting factor if you use classes for that.

Comment: Java allows multiple inheritance for interfaces and if you use AspectJ you can add implementations of methods directly to interfaces. Put both together and you get: Multiple implementation inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Abstract classes trade a shorter way of reusing implementation for the flexibility to provide multiple interfaces to the same object.

Unless you're playing code-golf, choosing the flexibility of interfaces is usually the better option.